# Do I need to worry about new startScan()/getScanResults() restrictions if both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 21?

Tags: android, android-wifi

My app stop working on Android Pie but my project (very old!) is

```
compileSdkVersion 21
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
```

Do you think I need to rewrite the code that uses WiFiManager to respect the latest Android security restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to publish to Google Play unless you [target API 26+](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk), so if you want to publish to Google Play or provide a experience that is consistent with other modern apps, you would need to rewrite your `WifiManager` code to comply with the latest Android security restrictions.